# php not running on server

Tags: php

My server was running PHP scripts perfectly up until now. I don't know what happen to my server, but the PHP scripts are not running, instead, it is automatically commented by the server. When I uploaded my php script to show PHPINFO, this is what gives me back:

```
<!--?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?-->
```

if you view the source code, you would see that my php scripts are commented. What should I do to get my PHP scripts running?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If this is something to do with the server, shouldn't you put it on Serverfault (like Stackoverflow but for server issues)? You can find it at http://serverfault.com/. Also, can you show your original code, or is that the original code?

Answer (score 0):

Does the same thing occur if you execute the script from the PHP command line interface?

Seems like something external is explicitly disabling PHP execution either at the web server level or software level. Are you using some type of framework around PHP which my be limiting PHP execution, ie CakePHP, joomla etc?